# UTF8 not working in LuaTeX in TeXLive 2010

Tags: luatex, unicode

I've been trying to set a document using lualatex in my TeXLive 2010 installation. Unfortunately, the non-ASCII characters are left out from the output. In the following minimal document produces a PDF with no warnings or errors but it only contains the second line. Using the inputenc package results in an error `Unicode char ... not set up for use with LaTeX.`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
číčí
abcd
\end{document}
```

pdflatex handles the document fine. My version of lualatex is

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.60.2-2010071421 (Web2C 2010) (rev 3736)
```

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT: For bonus points, how would I use the Bitstream Charter fonts? I use the mathdesign package, but with them (and even when loading `fontspec`, `fontenc` and/or `luaotfload`), the non-ASCII characters are missing :/

```
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to actually load a font that includes these characters. By default, lualatex uses the computer modern fonts. You can select a font with the `fontspec` package. Just loading `fontspec` without explicitly setting a font, makes lualatex use the latin modern fonts, which include the characters.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
číčí
abcd
\end{document}
```

gives [image: latin modern]

You can load any OTF or TTF font with the `fontspec` package. For details see [the fontspec manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf). I do not know if there is an Unicode aware version of Bitstream Charter, but you can use [Charis SIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charis_SIL), which is based on it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}  % sets the math font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}          % sets the document font
\begin{document}
číčí abcd $abcd$
\end{document}
```

[image: Charis SIL and mathdesign]

Note that you have to include `mathdesign` before `\setmainfont` so that it doesn't override the document font.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. However, how could I use Bitstream Charter? Does it also have an alternative?

Comment: (edited to include the answer to that question)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any font package except `fontspec` if you want to enjoy the benefits of Unicode and OpenType. The version of Charter which is freely available is a non-Unicode Type 1 font, so you shouldn't use it. Use e.g. Charis SIL which is based on Charter.