# how to generate a PDF with real UTF characters

Tags: luatex, unicode, characters

I'm using these settings:

```
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\selectlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

in order to write my documents in UTF-8 and get a PDF with all my italian accents in their right place. Everything works smoothly and the output is OK, except for the fact that what I get are not real accented characters, but those "accent workarounds" that latex usually does in place of using a UTF-8-font. The problem is not the document itself, but when I copy its content in another program. For instance, when I copy an "à" from my documents and I paste it into an editor, the result is an "a`". What I think is that it's not compiling with a font that supports UTF-8, am I right? I've also tried with luatex, but what I get is the same matter.
So: how can I obtain real utf-8 characters in my PDFs?

### Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twocolumn, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\selectlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

Ciao this is a test: à

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you have `\usepackage{ae}` in your document? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you have `cm-super` installed? Or are you loading a font package which supports `T1`? For example, `\usepackage{lmodern}` will use the Latin Modern family which supports the T1 encoding and, hence, properly supports accented characters.  Note that `inputenc` concerns your *input* encoding. It has nothing to do with the output. It lets you type e.g. `ẅ` rather than `\"w`. It doesn't affect whether the ẅ in the document is composite or not.

Comment: @egreg thanks! I've added a MWE in my question

Comment: @cfr I've tried to add it, but unfortunately nothing new seems to happen. Try to have a look to my working example I've just added

Comment: When I compile your code and copy the accented character from the pdf, it pastes this: à which is what I would expect. Which distribution of TeX are you using? Is it current? What does `pdflatex --version` give? That's assuming you are compiling with pdflatex. If not, what are you using? I see you tagged the question `luatex` but you mention trying that as an alternative. (You would want different code for that option.) What are you compiling this MWE with?

Comment: Can you please run this code: ``\documentclass{scrartcl}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}à\end{document}
`` through Luatex and report back?
I definitely get a single-character ``à`` (Unicode 0x00e0 / UTF-8 c3a0) when copying from the PDF.

Comment: Don't use `inputenc` and `fontenc` with LuaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @phg I run it, but what I obtain is this "à" that according to this website http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html? is a combination of two unicode

Comment: Did you follow the advice here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6067/14066 as others are suggesting?

Comment: Yep, I've tried it! I'm using `\setmainfont{Charis SIL}` and everything compiles smoothly with lualatex, but what I get is always a combination of two UTF characters